# Problem setting command-line console resolution. vbeinfo in grub2 does not report all resolutions

Tags: linux, terminal, resolution, grub, framebuffer

I have a Asus EEE PC 1005P which I installed a Command-line system on using the Alternate Installer CD of Ubuntu Lucid Lynx. Altough I think this is a general linux and grub2 question. I do not have (or want) the X Window System installed.

I want to change my console screen resolution (not inside X) to 1024x600. But it isn't reported when I use vbeinfo inside grub:

```
grub> vbeinfo
VBE info:   version: 3.0  OEM software rev: 1.0
            total memory: 8128 KiB
List of compatible video modes:
Legend: P=Packed pixel, D=Direct color, mask/pos=R/G/B/reserved
0x112:   640 x 480 x 32   Direct, mask: 8/8/8/8  pos: 16/8/0/24
0x114:   800 x 600 x 16   Direct, mask: 5/6/5/0  pos: 11/5/0/0
0x115:   800 x 600 x 32   Direct, mask: 8/8/8/8  pos: 16/8/0/24
0x101:   640 x 480 x 8    Packed
0x103:   800 x 600 x 8    Packed
0x111:   640 x 480 x 16   Direct, mask: 5/6/5/0  pos: 11/5/0/0
Configured VBE mode (vbe_mode) = ox101
grub>
```

Relevant parts of sudo lspci -v:

```
...     ...

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ac
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
        ...
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ac
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
        ...

...     ...
```

Any ideas on how I can set the console resultion like I want it?

**Added!**

sudo fbset -i:

```
mode "1024x600"
    geometry 1024 600 1024 600 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name            : inteldrmfb
    Address         : 0xd0830000
    Size            : 2457600
    Type            : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual          : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep        : 1
    YPanStep        : 1
    YWrapStep       : 0
    LineLength      : 4096
    MMIO Address    : 0xf7e00000
    MMIO Size       : 524288
    Accelerator     : No
```

Does it mean I have the driver? Any ideas on how to set it to 1024 x 600 in grub2?

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into some similar trouble with Grub's VBE.  Unfortunately, Grub cannot access any graphics modes that are not reported by your **vbeinfo** command.  Set Grub's graphics mode by setting **GRUB_GFXMODE**, and the console framebuffer by setting  **GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX**, in */etc/default/grub* and running *sudo update-grub* ([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#grub%20%28/etc/default/grub%29)).

The linux console is displayed on a framebuffer device; that's what the *inteldrmfb* device is (shown in your *fbset* ouput). The framebuffer may need to be enabled in your initrd.  If so, run the following to enable it:

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

I've seen several threads regarding configuring console framebuffers in Lucid. You may need to look into something similar.  This post [describes setting up *uvesafb*](http://idyllictux.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucidubuntu-10-04-high-resolution-plymouth-virtual-terminal-for-atinvidia-cards-with-proprietaryrestricted-driver/) by passing specific framebuffer options on the kernel commandline.  If this is needed in your case, you'd add something like *"nomodeset video=intelfb:mode_option=1024x600-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"* to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** in */etc/default/grub*.  (The *"intelfb"* in that line may need to be *"inteldrmfb"*, but I'm not certain.)  You may also need to add a line in */etc/initramfs-tools/modules* -- *"intelfb mode_option=1024x600-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap"* -- and then re-run the *update-initramfs* command above.

Another alternative mentioned in the last link would be to remove the *splash* kernel option (from **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT**), setting **GRUB_GFXMODE** and **GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX**, and re-running *update-grub*.

Other resources that may help:

- ["Setting a proper framebuffer"](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_Aspire_One#Setting_a_proper_framebuffer) on the ArchLinux Wiki's Acer Aspire One page
- [Kernel Mode Setting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/KernelModeSetting) at the Ubuntu Wiki

Comment: +1 The uvesafb trick on the page you mentioned made my Ubuntu 10.04 run beautifully inside a VMware server.